# Why is text alignment off in flexbox next to this image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to center a logo and and the words 'style guide' next to each other in the header. I'm using flexbox to do this, and the text positioning is weird. I thought it might have something to do with the fact that I scaled the logo to half size but I'm not certain and I can't seem to fix it. Does anyone know why this is happening?

The html:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://i1077.photobucket.com/albums/w474/skottunder/example-logo_zpsso7yyy5k.jpg"></img>
        <span id="header-text">Style Guide</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.header {
    background: #317cde;
    width: 100%;    
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;

    width: 320px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.header .container img {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    float: left;
}

#header-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 28px;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/victoria-mh/pen/wWqVwJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `align-items:center`.

```css
.header {
  background: #317cde;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 320px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* add this */
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.header .container img {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  float: left; /* can be removed */
}
#header-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  float: left; /* can be removed */
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://i1077.photobucket.com/albums/w474/skottunder/example-logo_zpsso7yyy5k.jpg" />
    <span id="header-text">Style Guide</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Your `float` statements are overridden by the `flex` statement.

Comment: You beat me by 50 secs :P

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now! 

It still doesn't look quite as nice as I want it to look though. The spacing between the text and the logo is quite large, it would be ideal if it was about the same or slightly larger than the space between style and guide. 

I have tried to fix this by changing margins and paddings and what not, but I can't seem to get them closer and I guess flexbox has something to do with this. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: That spacing *is* caused by the `transform`. The browser remembers the original size and allocates the space for the image as though it was still full size.